# PHP - How do you find duplicate value groupings in an array

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching

I have an array of string values which sometimes form repeating value patterns ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

```
$array = array(
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'c', 'd',
);
```

I would like to find duplicate patterns based on the array order and group them by that same order (to maintain it).

```
$patterns = array(
    array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')),
    array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('c'))
    array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('d'))
);
```

*Notice that [a,b], [b,c], & [c,d] are not patterns by themselves because they are inside the larger [a,b,c,d] pattern and the last [c,d] set only appears once so it's not a pattern either - just the individual values 'c' and 'd'*

Another example:

```
$array = array(
    'x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'b', 'a'
  //[.......] [.] [[......]  [......]] [.]
);
```

which produces

```
$patterns = array(
    array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('x')),
    array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('y')),
    array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('x', 'b')),
    array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('a'))
);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Well I'm trying to build a script for that but I don't understand why c and d are not in the same array.

Comment: @zeflex, good question. In truth I probably wouldn't care if they were grouped together. However, c and d are not a pattern in the sequence of things because I'm assuming the array always defaults to the longest pattern when two or more items repeat and a single item array when none of them repeat. In the case of [c,d] that pattern only shows up once by itself - so it's not a pattern just a two single array items. If it helps, think of this like preg_match_all() where it never includes previous match values in the consideration of what constitutes a "match".

Comment: I am trying to do some thing here, and have some questions 1. let assume we have a b c d and the next b a c d would that count as a b c d or only c d, 2. is there any roles for the pattern length of the duplicates or it is just random, 3. is it only letters, or would it have words or sentences?

Comment: The task is poorly defined, so it is complex to do something. Like in the first example, the longest pattern is the whole sequence ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', b',...,'c','d') repeated once, this way all others are shorter and should be excluded. Should we search only the repeated patterns? How then we have 'c' and 'd' in the output?

Comment: Also can we have multi-char elements as array elements? Or it is always single chars?

Comment: OK, regarding the logic, I think I got it - we need to "split the whole original array into longest adjacent non-overlapping patterns"

Comment: This is a good logic for zip

Comment: @Xeoncross I believe that anyone who answered the question, and attempted to do it correctly, would have spent a considerable amount of time doing this. While I think it's a good programming exercise, if the responses that are here aren't what you're looking for, could you please provide feedback as to what you are looking for or problems with the answers? There isn't a built in php function to do what you're looking for and every answer will have a considerable amount of code and take time to write.

Comment: @Xeoncross Sorry if my response seems rude, but it doesn't make sense to put a bounty on a question multiple times in a row, let it lapse, and not give any feedback to the 4 new answers, 2 of which were posted 2 days ago.

Comment: @DaveF, don't worry. I am not ignoring the answers here or going to let the bounty go to waste (stackoverflow has a "grace period" for bounties). In fact, your answer is the one I was most impressed with. I've been sick so I haven't been able to be on the computer lately. I will be providing comments when I can. I didn't make it to the top 2% of members accidentally. ;)

Comment: @Xeoncross Thanks. Sorry. I wouldn't care about reputation if it wasn't for the fact that it affects your what you can do on the site, such as being allowed to add comments, vote, and setting bounties.

Answer (score 7):

Character arrays are just strings. Regex is the king of string pattern matching. Add recursion and the solution is pretty elegant, even with the conversion back and forth from character arrays:

```
function findPattern($str){
    $results = array();
    if(is_array($str)){
        $str = implode($str);
    }
    if(strlen($str) == 0){ //reached the end
        return $results;
    }
    if(preg_match_all('/^(.+)\1+(.*?)$/',$str,$matches)){ //pattern found
        $results[] = array('number' => (strlen($str) - strlen($matches[2][0])) / strlen($matches[1][0]), 'values' => str_split($matches[1][0]));
        return array_merge($results,findPattern($matches[2][0]));
    }
    //no pattern found
    $results[] = array('number' => 1, 'values' => array(substr($str, 0, 1)));
    return array_merge($results,findPattern(substr($str, 1)));
}
```

You can test here : https://eval.in/507818 and https://eval.in/507815

Comment: Your assumption that it's an array of characters is nothing but sure. Op's message says "an array of string values"

Comment: Example: not working with `$input = array(
    'abc', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'ab', 'cb', 'c', 'd',
    'c', 'd',
);`

Comment: Is it actually a case? OP nor anyone else brought it up in examples. This may be over-engineering.

Comment: If it's not working with strings, then it's a case. And I just gave you an example.

Answer (score 5):

If c and d can be grouped, this is my code:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'c', 'd',
);

$res = array();

foreach ($array AS $value) {
    if (!isset($res[$value])) {
        $res[$value] = 0;
    }
    $res[$value]++;
}

foreach ($res AS $key => $value) {
    $fArray[$value][] = $key;
    for ($i = $value - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $fArray[$i][] = $key;
    }
}

$res = array();
foreach($fArray AS $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($res[serialize($value)])) {
        $res[serialize($value)] = 0;
    }
    $res[serialize($value)]++;
}
$fArray = array();
foreach($res AS $key => $value) {
    $fArray[] = array('number' => $value, 'values' => unserialize($key));
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($fArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Final result is:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'number' => int 2
      'values' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string 'a' (length=1)
          1 => string 'b' (length=1)
          2 => string 'c' (length=1)
          3 => string 'd' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'number' => int 1
      'values' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'c' (length=1)
          1 => string 'd' (length=1)
```

Comment: +1 That is a good start, but it doesn't preserve match order. If you add `['a', 'c', 'd']` onto the end of the array and run again it states the first match is `['a', 'c', 'd']` even though those are the last characters appended to the array.

Comment: Well yes. But it's not really clear, also add 'd', 'e', 'f', and see what's happening.

Comment: In your example I don't understand why you group the letter as this. Sorry if I make you wasting time to explain but I think you goal is not really clear.

Comment: sorry if it's still not clear. I'm looking for the largest repeating patterns in the sequence. In the example you posted `[c,d]` is not a pattern because it only appears once right before the end - so it's just individual values. (_The other two times it appears are inside the larger `[a,b,c,d]` pattern so they don't count_)

Comment: I am thinking I could do a for loop and use `array_slice()` to compare  groups of segments in the array looking to see if the next set of values is the same (from large to small).

Comment: @Xeoncross I think you are better to delete this question and create a new one but in the title put pregmatch. I think with a pregmatch it will simplify a lot the work.

Answer (score 5):

The following code will return the expected result, finding the longest portions with repeated values:

```
function pepito($array) {
  $sz=count($array);
  $patterns=Array();
  for ($pos=0;$pos<$sz;$pos+=$len) {
    $nb=1;
    for ($len=floor($sz/2);$len>0;$len--) {
      while (array_slice($array, $pos, $len)==array_slice($array, $pos+$len, $len)) {
        $pos+=$len;
        $nb++;
      }
      if ($nb>1) break;
    }
    if (!$len) $len=1;
    $patterns[]=Array('number'=>$nb, 'values'=>array_slice($array, $pos, $len));
  }
  return $patterns;
}
```

This will match with your examples:

> {['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}, ['c', 'd']
>
> or  {['x'], ['x']}, ['y'], {['x', 'b'], ['x', 'b']}, ['a']

The difficult part is more about examples like:

> {['one', 'one', 'two'], ['one', 'one', 'two']}

Or the most difficult choice to make:

> one, two, one, two, one, two, one, two

Because we can group this in both the form:

> [one, two], [one, two], [one, two], [one, two]
>
> [one, two, one, two], [one, two, one, two]

where there is no "evident" choice. My above algorithm will always consider the longest match, as this is the most easy implementation to consider any combination.

**EDIT: You should also consider cases where the longest match is after a shorter one**:

Example:

> 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'

If you start from left to right, you might want to group as :

> {['one', 'two'], ['one', 'two'],} 'three', 'four', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'

when you could group like:

> 'one', 'two', {['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']}

This situation has to be resolved with recursive calls to get the better solution but this will result in longer execution time:

```
function pepito($array) {
  if (($sz=count($array))<1) return Array();
  $pos=0;
  $nb=1;
  for ($len=floor($sz/2);$len>0;$len--) {
    while (array_slice($array, $pos, $len)==array_slice($array, $pos+$len, $len)) {
      $pos+=$len;
      $nb++;
    }
    if ($nb>1) break;
  }

  if (!$len) $len=1;
  $rec1=pepito(array_slice($array, $pos+$len));
  $rec2=pepito(array_slice($array, 1));

  if (count($rec1)<count($rec2)+1) {
    return array_merge(Array(Array('number'=>$nb, 'values'=>array_slice($array, $pos, $len))), $rec1);
  }
  return array_merge(Array(Array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array_slice($array, 0, 1))), $rec2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Definitions**:

**Pattern base**: The sequence of elements that repeat within a pattern. (ie. For [a,b,a,b,c], [a,b] is the pattern base and [a,b,a,b] is the pattern.

We want to start searching for the longest pattern base, followed by the next longest, and so forth. It's important to understand that if we find a pattern, we don't need to check within it for the start of another pattern with a base of the same length.

Here's the proof.

Assume that A is a pattern base, and that we've encountered the pattern AA. Assume that B is a another pattern base, of the same length, that forms a pattern starting within A. Let Y be the overlapping elements. If A=XY, then AA=XYXY. Since B is the same length, it must be the case that B=YX because in order to complete B we must use the remaining elements in A. Moreover, since B forms a pattern we must have BB, which is YXYX. Since A starts before B, we have XYXYX=AAX=XBB. If B repeats again, we would have XBBB=XYXYXYX=AAAX. Therefore, B cannot repeat an additional time without A repeating an additional time. Thus, we do not need to check for longer patterns within those generated by A.

The longest pattern possible consists of half the elements in the whole list because the simplest pattern can occur exactly twice. Thus, we can start checking for patterns of half of the length and work our way down to patterns of size 2.

Assuming that we search the array from left to right, if a pattern is found, we only need to search on either side of it for additional patterns. To the left, there are no patterns with bases of the same length, or they would have been discovered beforehand. Thus, we search the left side for patterns using the next smallest base size. The elements to the right of the pattern haven't been searched so we continue searching for patterns using a base of the same size.

The function to do this is as follows:

```
function get_patterns($arr, $len = null) {
    // The smallest pattern base length for which a pattern can be found
    $minlen = 2;

    // No pattern base length was specified
    if ($len === null) {
        // Use the longest pattern base length possible
        $maxlen = floor(count($arr) / 2);
        return get_patterns($arr, $maxlen);

    // Base length is too small to find any patterns
    } else if ($len < $minlen) {
        // Compile elements into lists consisting of one element

        $results = array();

        $num = 1;
        $elem = $arr[0];

        for ($i=1; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            if ($elem === $arr[$i]) {
                $num++;
            } else {
                array_push($results, array(
                    'number' => $num,
                    'values' => array( $elem )
                ));

                $num = 1;
                $elem = $arr[$i];
            }
        }

        array_push($results, array(
            'number' => $num,
            'values' => array( $elem )
        ));

        return $results;
    }

    // Cycle through elements until there aren't enough elements to fit
    //  another repition.
    for ($i=0; $i < count($arr) - $len * 2 + 1; $i++) {
        // Number of times pattern base occurred
        $num_read = 1; // One means there is no pattern yet

        // Current pattern base we are attempting to match against
        $base = array_slice($arr, $i, $len);

        // Check for matches using segments of the same length for the elements
        //  following the current pattern base
        for ($j = $i + $len; $j < count($arr) - $len + 1; $j += $len) {
            // Elements being compared to pattern base
            $potential_match = array_slice($arr, $j, $len);

            // Match found
            if (has_same_elements($base, $potential_match)) {
                $num_read++;

            // NO match found
            } else {
                // Do not check again using currently selected elements
                break;
            }
        }

        // Patterns were encountered
        if ($num_read > 1) {
            // The total number of elements that make up the pattern
            $pattern_len = $num_read * $len;

            // The elements before the pattern
            $before = array_slice($arr, 0, $i);

            // The elements after the pattern
            $after = array_slice(
                $arr, $i + $pattern_len, count($arr) - $pattern_len - $i
            );

            $results = array_merge(
                // Patterns of a SMALLER length may exist beforehand
                count($before) > 0 ? get_patterns($before, $len-1) : array(),

                // Patterns that were found
                array(
                    array(
                        'number' => $num_read,
                        'values' => $base
                    )
                ),

                // Patterns of the SAME length may exist afterward
                count($after) > 0 ? get_patterns($after, $len) : array()
            );

            return $results;
        }
    }

    // No matches were encountered

    // Search for SMALLER patterns
    return get_patterns($arr, $len-1);
}
```

The function `has_same_elements`, which was used to check if arrays with primitive keys are identical, is as follows:

```
// Returns true if two arrays have the same elements.
//
// Precondition: Elements must be primitive data types (ie. int, string, etc)
function has_same_elements($a1, $a2) {
    // There are a different number of elements
    if (count($a1) != count($a2)) {
        return false;
    }

    for ($i=0; $i < count($a1); $i++) {
        if ($a1[$i] !== $a2[$i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

In order to speed up the code, there are a few things that you could do. Instead of slicing the array, you can supply the function with indexes to the start and end position that are to be examined, along with the array. Also, using strings may be slow so you can create an array that maps strings to numbers and vice versa. Then you can convert the array of strings into an array of numbers and use it instead. After you get the result, you can convert the arrays of numbers back into strings.

I tested the function using the following code:

```
$tests = array(
    'a,b,c,d',
    'a',
    'a,a,a,a',
    'a,a,a,a,a',
    'a,a,a,a,a,a',
    'b,a,a,a,a,c',
    'b,b,a,a,a,a,c,c',
    'b,b,a,a,d,a,a,c,c',
    'a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,c,d',
    'x,x,y,x,b,x,b,a'
);

echo '<pre>';
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo '<div>';
    $arr = explode(',',$test);
    echo "$test<br /><br />";
    pretty_print(get_patterns($arr));
    echo '</div><br />';
}
echo '</pre>';
```

The function that I used to print the output, `pretty_print` is as follows:

```
function pretty_print($results) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $a = "array('" . implode("','", $result['values']) . "')";
        echo "array('number' => ${result['number']}, 'values' => $a)<br />";
    }
}
```

The output from the test code is as follows:

```
a,b,c,d

array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('a'))
array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('b'))
array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('c'))
array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('d'))

a

array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('a'))

a,a,a,a

array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('a','a'))

a,a,a,a,a

array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('a','a'))
array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('a'))

a,a,a,a,a,a

array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('a','a','a'))

b,a,a,a,a,c

array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('b'))
array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('a','a'))
array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('c'))

b,b,a,a,a,a,c,c

array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('b'))
array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('a','a'))
array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('c'))

b,b,a,a,d,a,a,c,c

array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('b'))
array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('a'))
array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('d'))
array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('a'))
array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('c'))

a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,c,d

array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('a','b','c','d'))
array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('c'))
array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('d'))

x,x,y,x,b,x,b,a

array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('x'))
array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('y'))
array('number' => 2, 'values' => array('x','b'))
array('number' => 1, 'values' => array('a'))
```

Comment: Good job, you take everything into account without making bad assumptions. Unfortunately, it is not working with 'a,b,c,a,a,b,c'. It gives {[a,b],[a,b]},[a],[b],[c].

Comment: @Adam Thank you for checking my code. It's somewhat complicated and I'm a little uneasy about it working perfectly because there are going to be test cases that I missed. The problem was that I used `continue` in the second loop that iterates through potential matches, and I should have used `break` to exit the loop. I've updated the code. Please let me know if you find anything else that's wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here is my take, the code below splits the whole original array into longest adjacent non-overlapping chunks.

So in the situation like this

```
'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' 
[                 ] [                 ] [ ]  [  ]  <-- use 2 long groups
[      ] [        ] [      ]  [       ] [ ]  [  ]  <-- and not 4 short
```

it will prefer 2 long groups to 4 shorter groups.

Update: also tested with examples from another answer, works for these cases too:

```
one, two, one, two, one, two, one, two
[one two one two], [one two one two]

'one' 'two' 'one' 'two' 'three' 'four' 'one' 'two' 'three' 'four'    
['one'] ['two'] ['one' 'two' 'three' 'four'] ['one' 'two' 'three' 'four']
```

Here is the code and tests:

```
<?php

/*
 * Splits an $array into chunks of $chunk_size.
 * Returns number of repeats, start index and chunk which has
 * max number of ajacent repeats.
 */
function getRepeatCount($array, $chunk_size) {
    $parts = array_chunk($array, $chunk_size);
    $maxRepeats = 1;
    $maxIdx = 0;
    $repeats = 1;
    $len = count($parts);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len-1; $i++) {
        if ($parts[$i] === $parts[$i+1]) {
            $repeats += 1;
            if ($repeats > $maxRepeats) {
                $maxRepeats = $repeats;
                $maxIdx = $i - ($repeats-2);
            }
        } else {
            $repeats = 1;
        }
    }
    return array($maxRepeats, $maxIdx*$chunk_size, $parts[$maxIdx]);
}

/*
 * Finds longest pattern in the $array.
 * Returns number of repeats, start index and pattern itself.
 */
function findLongestPattern($array) {
    $len = count($array);
    for ($window = floor($len/2); $window >= 1; $window--) {
      $num_chunks = ceil($len/$window);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $num_chunks; $i++) {
        list($repeats, $idx, $pattern) = getRepeatCount(
          array_slice($array, $i), $window
        );
        if ($repeats > 1) {
            return array($repeats, $idx+$i, $pattern);
        }
      }
    }
    return array(1, 0, [$array[0]]);
}

/*
 * Splits $array into longest adjacent non-overlapping parts.
 */
function splitToPatterns($array) {
    if (count($array) < 1) {
        return $array;
    }
    list($repeats, $start, $pattern) = findLongestPattern($array);
    $end = $start + count($pattern) * $repeats;
    return array_merge(
            splitToPatterns(array_slice($array, 0, $start)),
            array(
                array('number'=>$repeats, 'values' => $pattern)
            ),
            splitToPatterns(array_slice($array, $end))
    );
}
```

Tests:

```
function isEquals($expected, $actual) {
    $exp_str = json_encode($expected);
    $act_str = json_encode($actual);
    $equals = $exp_str === $act_str;
    if (!$equals) {
        echo 'Equals check failed'.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'expected: '.$exp_str.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'actual  : '.$act_str.PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $equals;
}

assert(isEquals(
    array(1, 0, ['a']), getRepeatCount(['a','b','c'], 1)
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(1, 0, ['a']), getRepeatCount(['a','b','a','b','c'], 1)
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(2, 0, ['a','b']), getRepeatCount(['a','b','a','b','c'], 2)
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(1, 0, ['a','b','a']), getRepeatCount(['a','b','a','b','c'], 3)
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(3, 0, ['a','b']), getRepeatCount(['a','b','a','b','a','b','a'], 2)
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(2, 2, ['a','c']), getRepeatCount(['x','c','a','c','a','c'], 2)
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(1, 0, ['x','c','a']), getRepeatCount(['x','c','a','c','a','c'], 3)
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(2, 0, ['a','b','c','d']),
    getRepeatCount(['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','c','d'],4)
));

assert(isEquals(
    array(2, 2, ['a','c']), findLongestPattern(['x','c','a','c','a','c'])
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(1, 0, ['a']), findLongestPattern(['a','b','c'])
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(2, 2, ['c','a']),
    findLongestPattern(['a','b','c','a','c','a'])
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(2, 0, ['a','b','c','d']),
    findLongestPattern(['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','c','d'])
));


// Find longest adjacent non-overlapping patterns
assert(isEquals(
    array(
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('a')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('b')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('c')),
    ),
    splitToPatterns(['a','b','c'])
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('a')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('b')),
        array('number'=>2, 'values'=>array('c','a')),
    ),
    splitToPatterns(['a','b','c','a','c','a'])
));
assert(isEquals(
    array(
        array('number'=>2, 'values'=>array('a','b','c','d')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('c')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('d')),
    ),
    splitToPatterns(['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','c','d'])
));
/*     'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', */
/*     [                 ] [                 ] [ ]  [  ] */
/* NOT [      ] [        ] [      ]  [       ] [ ]  [  ] */
assert(isEquals(
    array(
        array('number'=>2, 'values'=>array('a','b','a','b')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('c')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('d')),
    ),
    splitToPatterns(['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','c','d'])
));

/*     'x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'b', 'a' */
/* //  [  ] [  ] [ ]  [       ] [      ]  [ ] */
assert(isEquals(
    array(
        array('number'=>2, 'values'=>array('x')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('y')),
        array('number'=>2, 'values'=>array('x','b')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('a')),
    ),
    splitToPatterns(['x','x','y','x','b','x','b','a'])
));
// one, two, one, two, one, two, one, two
// [                ] [                 ]
assert(isEquals(
    array(
        array('number'=>2, 'values'=>array('one', 'two', 'one', 'two')),
    ),
    splitToPatterns(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])
));
// 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'
// [   ]  [   ]  [                           ]  [                           ]
assert(isEquals(
    array(
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('one')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('two')),
        array('number'=>2, 'values'=>array('one','two','three','four')),
    ),
    splitToPatterns(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'one', 'two', 'three','four'])
));

/*     'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', */
/*     [  ] [                 ] [                 ] [ ]  */
assert(isEquals(
    array(
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('a')),
        array('number'=>2, 'values'=>array('a','b','a','b')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('c')),
    ),
    splitToPatterns(['a','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','c'])
));

/* 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b' */
// [      ]  [      ]  [ ]  [ ]  [      ] [       ]  [      ]
assert(isEquals(
    array(
        array('number'=>2, 'values'=>array('a', 'b')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('c')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('d')),
        array('number'=>3, 'values'=>array('a','b')),
    ),
    splitToPatterns(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'])
));
/* 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', */
/* [  ] [  ] [  ] [                 ] [                 ] [ ]  */
assert(isEquals(
    array(
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('a')),
        array('number'=>2, 'values'=>array('a','b','a','b')),
        array('number'=>1, 'values'=>array('c')),
    ),
    splitToPatterns(['a','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','c'])
));
```

Answer (score 2):

I started with this now but at the end my brain burn and I don't know where to start to compare the arrays... Enjoy!

```
$array = array(
    'x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'b', 'a'
    //[.......] [.] [[......]  [......]] [.]
);

$arrayCount = count($array);

$res = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $arrayCount; $i++) {
    for($j = 1; $j < $arrayCount; $j++) {
        $res[$i][] = array_slice($array, $i, $j);
    }
}

//echo '<pre>';
//var_dump($res);
//echo '</pre>';
//
//die;


$resCount = count($res);
$oneResCount = count($res[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

First make a function which will find the possible group matches in the array for a given group array, starting from a specific index in the array and will return the number of matches found.

```
function findGroupMatch($group, $array, $startFrom) {
    $match = 0;
    while($group == array_slice($array, $startFrom, count($group))) {
        $match++;
        $startFrom += count($group);
    }
    return $match;
}
```

Now, we need to iterate through each item to find possible groups and then send it to `findGroupMatch()` function to check if any match for the group exists in the next items. The trick to find a possible group is finding an item which matches any of the previous items. If so, we find a possible group taking all the previous items starting from the matched item. Otherwise we just increase the list of unmatched items and at the end we enter all unmatched items as single item groups. (In the given example, we have `a, b, c, d, a....` When we find 2nd `a` in the array, it matches the previous `a`, So, we consider `a, b, c, d` a possible group and send it to function `findGroupMatch()`, to check how many more groups we can find in the next items.)

```
$array = array(
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'c', 'd',
);

$unMatchedItems = array();
$totalCount = count($array);
$groupsArray = array();

for($i=0; $i < $totalCount; $i++) {
    $item = $array[$i];

    if(in_array($item, $unMatchedItems)) {
        $matched_keys = array_keys($unMatchedItems, $item);
        foreach($matched_keys as $key) {
            $possibleGroup = array_slice($unMatchedItems, $key);

            $matches = findGroupMatch($possibleGroup, $array, $i);

            if ($matches) {
                //Insert the items before group as single item group
                if ($key > 0) {
                    for ($j = 0; $j < $key; $j++) {
                        $groupsArray[] = array('number' => 1, 'values' => array($unMatchedItems[$j]));
                    }
                }
                //Insert the group array
                $groupsArray[] = array('number' => $matches + 1, 'values' => $possibleGroup); //number includes initial group also so $matches + 1
                $i += (count($possibleGroup) * $matches) - 1; //skip the matched items from next iteration
                //Empty the unmatched array to start with a new group search
                $unMatchedItems = array();
                break;
            }
        }
        //If there was no matches, add the item to the unMatched group
        if(!$matches) $unMatchedItems[] = $item;
    } else {
        $unMatchedItems[] = $item;
    }

}

//Insert the remaining items as single item group
for($k=0; $k<count($unMatchedItems); $k++) {
    $groupsArray[] = array('number' => 1, 'values' => array($unMatchedItems[$k]));
}

print_r($groupsArray);
```

The Result will be like this: (Check this [PHP Fiddle](https://eval.in/507332) for testing and also https://eval.in/507333 for your another input test.)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [number] => 2
        [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [number] => 1
        [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        )

    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [number] => 1
        [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
        )

    )

)
```

Comment: Will not always find the longest matching element: (example: `'a', 'a','b', 'a', 'b'`)

Answer (score 2):

The *first* example is super easy with recursion. The *second* example... not so easy.

The example below works for only the first example by assuming no pattern should ever contain two of the same element. This will also handle all individual element patterns at the end of the original array and keep the pattern order (of the first pattern occurrence).

```
function find_pattern($input, &$result) {
    $values = []; // currently processed elements
    $pattern = ''; // the current element pattern
    $dupe_found = false; // did we find a duplicate element?

    // search the values for the first that matches a previous value
    while ($next = array_shift($input)) {
        // check if the element was already found
        if (in_array($next, $values)) {
            // re-add the value back into the input, since the next call needs it
            array_unshift($input, $next);

            // add the resulting pattern
            add_pattern($pattern, $values, $result);

            // find the next pattern with a recursive call
            find_pattern($input, $result);

            // a duplicate element was found!
            $dupe_found = true;

            // the rest of the values are handled by recursion, break the while loop
            break;
        } else {
            // not already found, so store the element and keep going
            $values[] = $next;

            // use the element to produce a key for the result set
            $pattern .= $next;
        }
    }

    // if no duplicate was found, then each value should be an individual pattern
    if (!$dupe_found) {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            add_pattern($value, [$value], $result);
        }
    }
}

function add_pattern($pattern, $values, &$result) {
    // increment the pattern count
    $result[$pattern]['number'] = isset($result[$pattern]['number']) ?
        result[$pattern]['number']+1 : 1;

    // add the current pattern to the result, if not already done
    if (!isset($result[$pattern]['values'])) {
        $result[$pattern]['values'] = $values;
    }
}
```

And an example usage:

```
$input = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'c', 'd'
];

$result = [];
find_pattern($input, $result);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

The example output:

```
Array
(
    [abcd] => Array
    (
        [number] => 2
        [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )
    )

    [c] => Array
    (
        [number] => 1
        [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        )
    )

    [d] => Array
    (
        [number] => 1
        [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: You're right, the second example was not providing the correct output. After taking another look, I was unable to come up with a more elegant solution when compared to the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'c', 'd'
);

// Call this function to get your patterns
function patternMatching(array $array) {
    $patterns = array();
    $belongsToPattern = array_fill(0, count($array), false);

    // Find biggest patterns first
    for ($size = (int) (count($array) / 2); $size > 0; $size--) {

        // for each pattern: start at every possible point in the array
        for($start=0; $start <= count($array) - $size; $start++) {

            $p = findPattern($array, $start, $size);

            if($p != null) {

                /* Before we can save the pattern we need to check, if we've found a
                 * pattern that does not collide with patterns we've already found */
                $hasConflict = false;
                foreach($p["positions"] as $idx => $pos) {
                    $PatternConflicts = array_slice($belongsToPattern, $pos, $p["size"]);
                    $hasConflict = $hasConflict || in_array(true, $PatternConflicts);
                }

                if(!$hasConflict) {

                    /* Since we have found a pattern, we don't want to find more 
                     * patterns for these positions */
                    foreach($p["positions"] as $idx => $pos) {
                        $replace = array_fill($pos, $p["size"], true);
                        $belongsToPattern = array_replace($belongsToPattern, $replace);
                    }

                    $patterns[] = $p;
                    // or only return number and values:
                    // $patterns[] = [ "number" => $p["number"], "values" => $p["values"]];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $patterns;
}


function findPattern(array $haystack, $patternStart, $patternSize ) {

    $size = count($haystack);
    $patternCandidate = array_slice($haystack, $patternStart, $patternSize);

    $patternCount = 1;
    $patternPositions = [$patternStart];

    for($i = $patternStart + $patternSize; $i <= $size - $patternSize; $i++) {

        $patternCheck = array_slice($haystack, $i, $patternSize);

        $diff = array_diff($patternCandidate, $patternCheck);

        if(empty($diff)) {
            $patternCount++;
            $patternPositions[] = $i;
        }

    }

    if($patternCount > 1 || $patternSize <= 1) {

        return [
            "number"    => $patternCount,
            "values"    => $patternCandidate,

            // Additional information needed for filtering, sorting, etc.
            "positions" => $patternPositions,
            "size"      => $patternSize
        ];
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

$patterns = patternMatching($array);

print "<pre>";
print_r($patterns);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

The code might be far from being optimal in speed but it should do what you want to do for any sequence of strings in an array. `patternMatching()` returns the patterns ordered descending in size of the pattern and ascending by first occurence (You can use `['positions'][0]` as a sorting criteria to achieve a different order).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<?php

$array = array(
  'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'a',
  'ab', 'c', 'd',
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
  'c', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'b',
  'x', 'y', 'b', 'c', 'd'
);


// convert the array to a string
$string = '';
foreach ($array as $a) {
  $l = strlen($a)-1;
  $string .= ($l) ? str_replace('::',':',$a[0] . ':' . substr($a,1,$l-1) . ':' . $a[$l]) . '-' : $a . '-';
}

// find patterns
preg_match_all('/(?=((.+)(?:.*?\2)+))/s', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $m) {
  $temp = str_replace('--','-',$m[2].'-');
  $patterns[] = ($temp[0]==='-') ? substr($temp,1) : $temp;
}

// remove empty values and duplicates
$patterns = array_keys(array_flip(array_filter($patterns)));

// sort patterns
foreach ($patterns as $p) {
  $sorted[$p] = strlen($p);
}
arsort($sorted);

// find double or more occurences
$stringClone = $string;
foreach ($sorted as $s=>$n) {
  $nA = substr_count($stringClone,':'.$s);
  $nZ = substr_count($stringClone,$s.':');
  $number = substr_count($stringClone,$s);
  $sub = explode('-',substr($stringClone,strpos($stringClone,$s),$n-1));
  $values = $sub;
  if($nA>0 || $nZ>0){
    $numberAdjusted = $number - $nA - $nZ;
    if($numberAdjusted > 1) {
      $temp = '';
      while($n--){
        $temp .= '#';
      }
      $position = strpos(str_replace(':'.$s,':'.$temp,str_replace($s.':',$temp.':',$string)),$s);
      $stringClone = str_replace(':'.$s,':'.$temp,$stringClone);
      $stringClone = str_replace($s.':',$temp.':',$stringClone);
      $result['p'.sprintf('%09d', $position)] = array('number'=>$numberAdjusted,'values'=>$values);
      $stringClone = str_replace($s,'',$stringClone);
      $stringClone = str_replace($temp,$s,$stringClone);
    }
  } else if($number>1){
    $position = strpos($string,$s);
    $result['p'.sprintf('%09d', $position)] = array('number'=>$number,'values'=>$values);
    $stringClone = str_replace($s,'',$stringClone);
  }
}

// add the remaining items
$remaining = array_flip(explode('-',substr($stringClone,0,-1)));
foreach ($remaining as $r=>$n) {
    $position = strpos($string,$r);
    $result['p'.sprintf('%09d', $position)] = array('number'=>1,'values'=>str_replace(':','',$r));
}

// sort results
ksort($result);
$result = array_values($result);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Working example [here](https://eval.in/510574).